# sending multiple emails simultaneously from database in php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send multiple emails to respective emails address from the database using the mail function.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select emails from email_test");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
 $to = $row['emails'];
 $subject ="testing bulkmail";
 $header = "from:noreply"; 
 $message ="Testing mail funtion.";
 $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

   if ($mail) {
  $output.= "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>E-mail send succesfully on registered E-mail Addresses</div>";
} else {
  $output.= '<div class="alert alert-dismissable fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Error! please Try After Sometime</div>';
  }        
}

if(isset($output)){
echo $output;
 }
```

Right now I have 4 emails address in the `emails` column and all email address is different from each other when I run the script the email only received on 2 email address only. what I trying to do is send emails to all email Address that are present in the database. I am looking a best or better way to implement this script, any help and suggestion is highly apprecheated.

Comment: Stuffing four recipients into one To: field is a great spam indicator.

Comment: see your database email 3rd one should be the wrong one.when that happens ```PHP``` mailer terminate all duty.
you can also use ```phpmailer``` plugin

Comment: what do you meant by 3rd emails is wrong?